# Firebase blaze plan Upgrade Issue: Unable to Verify Payment Information

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried upgrading my Firebase project from Spark to Blaze, but kept getting the “Unable to verify your payment information” error.

Tried using 4 different debit cards from India but it still keeps showing the same issue. Could anyone please assist me in resolving this issue? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or steps I can take to successfully upgrade to the Blaze plan.